Test wp.data with Jest in Block Plugin
I am trying to get my head around testing my Wordpress Block Plugin with Jest. I am specifically struggling how to mock calls to wp.data.
See the following function:
import apiFetch from '@wordpress/api-fetch';

export const initPageLink = async (useShortlink) => {
    const postId = wp.data.select('core/editor').getCurrentPostId();

    if (!postId) {
        throw new Error('No post ID available.');
    }

    if (useShortlink) {
        const post = await apiFetch({ path: `/wp/v2/posts/${postId}?context=edit` });
        const shortlink = `${post.link.replace(/\/[^\/]*$/, '')}/?p=${post.id}`;
        return shortlink;
    } else {
        const post = await apiFetch({ path: `/wp/v2/posts/${postId}` });
        return post.link;
    }
};

What is the best way to mock apiFetch and then specifically calls to wp.data in a jest test file.
Thanks
Sina
